# Pythagorean Triples, $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $b^2+c^2=d^2$. Is it possible?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I'm trying to solve a problem, and it would be solved if I could find a solution to the above system, $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $b^2+c^2=d^2$  for natural numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible by [Fermat's right triangle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_right_triangle_theorem).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try another approach to solving my problem now. And read the article to get a better understanding.

Comment: If you can tell us what the original problem is, we can help you.

Comment: @TobyMak Sounds like a good idea, I'll post another question and link it in the comments here.

Comment: @TobyMak https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917661/problem-1-2-14-b-in-symbolic-dynamics-and-coding